# Cannot make array in using tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

In feeding batch_xs to x, I reshaped batch_xs, for BATCH_SIZE is 1.
Here is my source.
I'm not sure what is making the ValueError.

```
with tf.name_scope("input") as scope:
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1, 784])

BATCH_SIZE = 1
DROP_OUT_RATE = 0.4
EPOCH = 1
MEMORIZE = 10
accuracy_array = []
loss = tf.nn.l2_loss(y - x) / BATCH_SIZE
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(loss)

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)
mnist_list = make_mnist_train_list(55000, 10)
test_list = make_mnist_test_list(5000, 10)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

for i in range(EPOCH):
    for j in range(5500/BATCH_SIZE):
        batch_xs = tf.reshape(mnist_list[0][j*BATCH_SIZE:j*BATCH_SIZE+1], [1, 784])
        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, keep_prob: (1.0 - DROP_OUT_RATE), r_keep_prob: (1.0 - DROP_OUT_RATE)})
        if (i +1)% MEMORIZE == 0:
            accuracy_array.append(loss.eval(session=sess, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, keep_prob: 1.0, r_keep_prob: 1.0}))
            print(accuracy_array[ int(math.floor((i+1)/MEMORIZE -1))])
```

This gives me the Value error, which doesn't make sense to me.

ValueError: Argument must be a dense tensor

Comment: Your code mentions "tf.nn.l2_loss(y - x) / BATCH_SIZE" but doesn't define y anywhere.  Is this the complete example?  Also please include the full text of the error, which hopefully indicates the line causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/api_docs/python/client.html#Session) :

> Each key in feed_dict can be one of the following types:
>
> - If the key is a Tensor, the value may be a Python scalar, string, list, or numpy ndarray that can be converted to the same dtype as that tensor. Additionally, if the key is a placeholder, the shape of the value will be checked for compatibility with the placeholder.
> - If the key is a SparseTensor, the value should be a SparseTensorValue.

The types that you can use as the "value" for a key in `feed_dict` should be Python primitive types or numpy arrays. You are using the result of `tf.reshape`, which is a TensorFlow Tensor type. You can simply use `np.reshape` if you want to feed a reshaped array.